# CREATING SUBSETS IN SAS "automatically"

Tags: sas, dataset, subset

I have generated a dataset through sas consisting of 144 rows and now I want to create 18 subsets of the dataset (each subset containing 8 rows). I know how to create subsets "manually using the `firstobs=` and `obs=` commands.  However, I want the subsets to be created "automatically". The reason for this is that I am extracting data from a particular website and each time I run the code the dataset is of different size, all I know is that each time I generate a dataset I want to create X subsets containing 8 rows (e.g the first subset will consist of rows 1-8, the second will consist of rows 9-16 and so on...).

So my question, how do I go about attacking this problem?

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macro approach:

I just provided a rough code. Optimize it according to your requirements.

```
proc sql;
    select count(*) into :total from source_data;
quit;

%macro create_subsets(count,ds);

    %let cnt=%sysfunc(ceil(%sysevalf(&count/8)));

    %let num=1;


    %do i=1 %to &cnt;

        %if(&i = &cnt) %then %do;
            %let toread=&count;
        %end;
        %else %do;
            %let toread=&num+7;
        %end;

        data &ds._&i;
            set &ds(firstobs=&num obs=%eval(&toread));
        run;

        %let num=%eval(&num + 8);
    %end;

%mend create_subsets;

%create_subsets(&total,source_data)
```

Edited based on the valuable comment from Robert.
*Note: A non macro approach will always be easier and more efficient.*

Comment: While a macro approach would work, a non-macro solution is almost always better than a macro solution (easier to read/maintain/fewer bugs, etc.).  Additionally, this approach will read the source dataset 8 times.  That means it's going to be 8 times slower.  Finally, you should also consider parameterizing the `8` value so that the person calling the macro can choose how many subsets they want.

Comment: Thanks Kay! The macro has worked and is successfully creating the required subsets. I have one more question I now want to transpose the X subsets and merge them based on some variables.. Again I know how to transpose and merge datasets together, but how would I go about adding the transpose and merge functions into the macro so it works for any number of subset? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: My ability to use macro in sas is very limited.... I'm new at this piece of software.

Comment: I figured out how to transpose the dataset using the macro :)

Comment: Hi I figured out both the transpose and merge statements to add to the macro that you provided me with. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the purpose of your subsets is, but it's generally a bad idea to split datasets up into multiple versions.  The better approach is to create a variable in the original dataset that holds the subset number, that way it is easy to extract particular subsets or group by them later on.

Here's an easy way to do that, clearly the final subset will not have 8 rows if the number of records is not divisible by 8.  I assumed from your question that 8 rows is a fixed amount regardless of record size.

```
data want;
set sashelp.citimon;
subset = ceil(_n_/8);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Kieth. I appreciate the guidance!